# Text Area not updating after using useState and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, textarea

I have the following code snippet below. Essentially, I am trying to use useEffect and useState to update a text area with a template message so the user doesn't have to fill everything out. See code below

```
//State variable for message
const [message, onMessageChange] = useState();   

//Update the message with template when user variable changes
useEffect(() => {
    onMessageChange(`Hi ${user?.userData?.firstname}, I need help with ...`);
}, [user]); 

.
.
.

const handleMessageChange = event => {
  // ️ update textarea value
  onMessageChange(event.target.value);
};

//Text area with updated value
<textarea value={message} onChange={handleMessageChange}></textarea>
```

When the user variable is updated, the value of the message in the text area updates to the template, however, it makes the text area immutable. Any attempted to edit the message in the text area does not work.

When I take out the useEffect call, it works perfectly fine but leaves me without the template.

Is there something I'm missing with regards to using useEffect and useState?

Comment: in textarea try **defaultValue={`Hi ${user?.userData?.firstname}, I need help with ...`}** and remove the useEffect

Comment: I tried your code it's working fine with useEffect maybe you're having something else affecting your code

Comment: The default value prop worked. Thank you @monim

Comment: that is great !

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the default value prop in text area instead and it worked.

```
//Text area with updated value
<textarea defaultValue={`Hi ${user?.userData?.firstname}, I need help with ...`} 
value={message} 
onChange={handleMessageChange}>
</textarea>
```